# How to exclude benchmarks of the certain category in the BDN CLI?

Tags: .net, performance, command-line-interface, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I have 10 benchmark classes in my project. A few are marked with the "Long" [BenchmarkCategory](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/samples/IntroCategories.html). In the CI, I want to dry run all but long benchmarks. How to do this using Benchmark.NET Command Line Interface?

In the [docs](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/console-args.html), I see:

- `--anyCategories` - runs all benchmarks that belong to any of the provided categories
- `--allCategories` - runs all benchmarks that belong to all provided categories

But I just want to mark a few benchmarks as `[BenchmarkCategory("Long")]` and run everything else by default. I feel I am missing something.